# How can I show Image buttons based on field data in a asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0

I Like to add Image buttons in a Databound ASP.NET 4.0 `GridView` for a Boolean field in a way that if it is true show one image and if it is false show another image.

`ImageField` does not give me click ability and I don't know how to change image on buttons based on field value. With Button trigger I will run a stored procedure to change the state of Boolean field.

I'm using C# for programming

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also a very simple and straight forward solution would be to use two image fields, and hide one or the other depending upon your boolean value.

Comment: Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsApproved")) %>' or 
Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Bind("IsApproved")) %>' is the easiest answer. thanks Pratik to send me to right direction

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1:-

Create a template field and place your image button in it.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="myImageButton" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

### Step 2:-

Then inside your `RowDataBound` event check the condition and assign the image url

```
protected void gridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ImageButton myImageButton = e.Row.FindControl("myImageButton") as ImageButton;
        if (myImageButton != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "myBooleanField")))
            {
                myImageButton.ImageUrl = "image1.jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                myImageButton.ImageUrl = "image2.jpg";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all use Template Field and place a ImageButton then assign a code Behind method to the ImageUrl attribute,this method will return the path of image based upon the 'Status'.
Also make use of the CommandArgument attribute to store the Status, which can be used to update the 'Status' to the database when the button is clicked.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImgBtnStatus" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Status") %>'  ImageUrl='<%# Bind_Image(Eval("Status").ToString()) %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here we are calling a code behind method and it looks as shown below.

```
public string Bind_Image(string Status)
{
    bool status = Convert.ToBoolean(Status);
    // If Status is true , bind the img_true.bmp
    if (status)
    {
        return "~/images/img_true.bmp";
    }
    else
    {
        return "~/images/img_false.bmp";
    }
}
```